# Combine Two Strings to one address in MIPS Assembly

Tags: assembly, mips

I have a MIPS program I am writing, in which the user types in their first name, then last name, and then the system prints out their full name.

I store both names in seperate registers, but I need to combine them to one before I print the full name out.

Any help would be appreciated. Code is below:

```
.data
first:.asciiz "Please enter your first name: \n"
last:.asciiz "Please enter your last name: \n"
full:.asciiz "Your full name is: "
.text 
main:
#    First Name
li $v0, 4              # 4 prints a line
la $a0, first          # Print first name text
syscall                # Syscall

add $a1, $a1, 254      # Setting String length 
li $v0, 8              # 8 will read string
syscall                # calls the word
sw $v0, first
move $v0, $t1          # The name is now in $t1

#   Last Name
li $v0, 4              # 4 prints a line
la $a0, last           # Print last name text
syscall                # Syscall

li $v0, 8              # 8 will read string
syscall                # calls the word
sw $v0, last
move $v0, $t2          # The name is now in $t2

#    Full Name
li $v0, 4              # 4 prints a line
la $a0, full           # Print full name text
syscall  

    # Combine first and last name below
```

Comment: Why can't you just print each separately?

Comment: @CarlNorum Just part of the learning process I am teaching myself. The requirements call for "The output string should be stored in a memory segment separate from the segments used to store the two input strings."

Comment: So that's telling you exactly what to do, then.

Comment: @CarlNorum Any resources on how to go about doing that? (New to this)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing that needs to be said here is that you're using the read-string system call wrong. You seem to think that the system call is returning an address in $v0, and this is not the case. You can find some info on MIPS system calls [here](http://courses.missouristate.edu/kenvollmar/mars/help/syscallhelp.html).

The second is that you appear to be attempting to re-use the memory you reserved for your prompts for the user's first and last names. This is a bad idea.

The first thing is to fix your data segment:

```
.data

fprompt:.asciiz "Please enter your first name: "
lprompt:.asciiz "Please enter your last name: "
oprompt:.asciiz "Your full name is: "
first: .space 255 #255 bytes for first name
last:  .space 255 #255 bytes for last name
full:  .space 512 #512 bytes for full name
```

Next, the main function has to be fixed as the wrong convention for the read string call is being used:

```
main:

    #Prompt for first name
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, fprompt
    syscall

    #Enter first name
    la $a0, first
    li $a1, 255
    li $v0, 8
    syscall

    #Prompt for last name
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, lprompt
    syscall

    #Enter last name
    la $a0, last
    li $a1, 255
    li $v0, 8
    syscall

    #Display output lead-up
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, oprompt
    syscall

    #call the strcpy function
    move $s0 $ra
    la $a0 first
    la $a1 last
    la $a2 full
    jal strcpy
    move $ra $s0

    #display the full string
    la $a0 full
    li $v0 4
    syscall

    #display a new-line
    li $a0 10
    li $v0 11
    syscall

    #exit
    jr $ra
```

Finally, for the meet of the question is how to concatenate two strings. For this I used a separate function called strcpy (which should be noted does NOT perform the same as C's strcpy). The strcpy takes the 2 input strings in $a0 and $a1 and copies them to $a2. It also throws a space in between for good measure.

```
strcpy:

    li $t8 10 #store newline in $t8

    #loop through first string and copy to output string
   sCopyFirst:

        lb   $t0 0($a0)
        beq  $t0 $zero sCopySpace #exit loop on null byte
        beq  $t0 $t8 sCopySpace   #exit loop on new-line
        sb   $t0 0($a2)
        addi $a0 $a0 1
        addi $a2 $a2 1
        b sCopyFirst

    sCopySpace:

        li   $t0 ' '
        sb   $t0 0($a2)
        addi $a2 $a2 1 

    #loop through second string and copy to output string 
    sCopySecond:

        lb   $t0 0($a1)
        beq  $t0 $zero sDone #exit on null byte
        beq  $t0 $t8 sDone   #exit on new-line
        sb   $t0 0($a2)
        addi $a1 $a1 1
        addi $a2 $a2 1
        b sCopySecond

    sDone:

        sb $zero 0($a2) #null terminate string
        jr $ra
```